# Unix: Filter & Manipulate Column Data in CSV

Tags: linux, csv, unix, awk, sed

In Unix, how could I transform a CSV file from:

```
"0.4542703549","PRO000029D00QWERT","1.562"
"0.1585242685","PRO000030K00QWERT","4.833"
"0.4542703549","PRO000031K00QWERT","0.011"
"0.8917651385","PRO000032K00QWERT","3.057"
```

To:

```
"29","0.4542703549","1.562"
"30","0.1585242685","4.833"
"31","0.4542703549","0.011"
"32","0.8917651385","3.057"
```

In essence, I would like to strip everything from the second column (except digits 1-9) and then swap the position of columns 1 & 2.

Thank you in advance for your help..

Comment: you can try `sed -r 's/^(.*),"PRO0*([0-9]+).*,(.*)$/"\2",\1,\3/g' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simpliest with sed

```
sed 's/\("[^"]*"\),"PRO0*\([0-9]\{1,\}\)[^"]*"/\"\2",\1/' YourFile
```

alternative

```
awk -F ',' -v 'quote="' '{print quote substr($2,5,6) + 0 quote "," $1 "," $3 }' YourFile
```

Comment: Just a correction: the comma after $1 in the awk command should be enclosed in quotes: `awk -F ',' -v 'quote="' '{print quote substr($2,5,6) + 0 quote "," $1 "," $3 }' YourFile`

Comment: right, forget by an habit of printf, post corrected